# Why does java.lang.reflect.Modifier have a public constructor?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm learning java reflection and I'm curious to know what use java.lang.reflect.Modifier has for a public constructor.  The java documentation doesn't give any description or use for it and the class has only static methods and constants.

EDIT: Added some test code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

  public class TestModifier {
        Modifier modifier = new Modifier(); // Compiles fine.
       // Math math = new Math(); // Won't compile.  Math() has private access.
}
```

Comment: You can extend it and have all those statics available to your code without qualification, even before `import static`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor exists and it's present in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#Modifier%28%29) although no info is present. 
I found some information about it in the a source code comment in the [GNU classpath](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/), a project that is and I quote:

> (GNU Classpath, Essential Libraries for Java,) is a GNU project to create free core class libraries for use with virtual machines and compilers for the java programming language.

In their [source code for the Modifier class](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/reflect/Modifier-source.html) you can find the following non-javadoc comment for the constructor:

> This constructor really shouldn't be here ... there are no instance methods or variables of this class, so instantiation is worthless.  However, this function is in the 1.1 spec, so it is added for completeness.

I don't know if this is totally accurate since I could only access Java 1.3.1 spec and in the [reflection model part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/spec/java-reflectionTOC.doc.html) of it what you can read is (bold's mine):

> The Modifier class is an **uninstantiable** class that exports class methods to decode Java language modifiers for classes and members. The language modifiers are encoded in an integer, and use the encoding constants defined by The Java Virtual Machine Specification.

I do wanna believe in the comment from the source code, but I can't really point you at the specification where such thing is said.. Even stranger to me is that the previous quote even being from spec 1.3 already states that it's uninstantiable.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not an error in javadoc. You can't find such a constructor means this is a default constructor (no arg constructor) which is by default public because the java.lang.reflect.Modifier is a public class.

Comment: Even if a class is public you can define it's default constructor has private in order to avoid instantiation.

Comment: @pabrantes Yes you can have a private constructor for a public class but my point is that in this case java doc has nothing to do if you can't see a default constructor in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the property of `javadoc` if used with default options , that it provides `default constructor` in documentation if the Parameter-less constructor is not defined for that class and there is no other constructor with parameters.

Comment: Even if that's the case it still leaves the question "why is the Modifier default constructor public instead of private" :)

Comment: @pabrantes: because if default constructor is `private` then it can't be inherited...And if it is `default` then it can't be inherited outside that package.. And if the class doesn't want itself to be inherited it would use `final` keyword instead :) .

Comment: Totally agree with you from a semantical point of view! But conceptually why would you need it anyway? Even when extending, the class is just an helper with everything static? Don't get me wrong, I don't wanna look stubborn but there's something "smelly" about the design in this particular case... or maybe it's just me;)

Comment: @pabrantes Even if that class is helper , it doesn't mean that we can't create more helpful class by extending it. By this way we are saved from the hard work of redefining those methods right from the scratch :).

Comment: Notice that by hard work redefining methods you're, in this case, referring to a single default constructor with no code at all ;)

Comment: @pabrantes: No , I am referring to those static methods :) . If class `MyModifier` extends `Modifier` then we can surely call `MyModifier.isPublic(int mod)` and other static methods of `Modifier`

Comment: Yep, but you don't need Modifier's constructor to be public to extend it and and still use everything. If Modifier's constructor was private, you could still have MyModifier extends it and doing everything with no problem. Anyway I'm totally moving you out of topic and SO is warning me about to avoid long discussions, was nice to exchange ideas with you!

Comment: @pabrantes : yeah SO is warning me too to avoid long discussion but before moving out I would say that your assumption that MyModifier extends Modifier even if Modifier's constructor is private, is absolutely wrong. You already know the dynamics , how child class constructor calls super() in first line of its body :) . Nice to exchange idea with you too .. TC :)

Comment: You're totally right, my brain was failing to think that super() only refers to the direct subClass (friday night...). Obviously it's unable to jump to Object's default constructor.. sorry about it (after all it seems it was me being stubborn all the way) and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good find, this is an oversight of the API designer.

But, it also proves that it is not a big deal at all to instantiate a utility class; `new Modifier()` has never caused anybody any problem. Neither would `new Math()`.

Don't listen to chicken little.